# Facebook ApiGraph Insights from photo

Tags: facebook, facebook-insights

I have an Android app with Facebook login. I am using the [ASNE library](https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE) with the next scopes: read_insights, read_stream, publish_actions, email,public_profile, user_friends.

The user I am login with, has the tester role in the developer console of facebook.

Now, I am saving the token of the user in my server (generated from the phone), and from the android device I send to my server the photo and my server is posting successfully the photo in the wall of the user (using the previous token) and I get back the PostId.

Now, I want to get the insights of this post but I the data object is empty.

I check the token permissions and it is ok:

[image: Token debugger]

And the screenshot of the insights response:

[image]

If I post the picture in a page, I get the insights from this post. For example:

[image]

Thanks for all, and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get insights for user posts but only for page posts: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/insights
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/platforminsights/page

If the post you're talking about is a page's post, please file a bug here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: I am still trying it, but insights are empty. I dont know why :S